# Html.ActionLink forwarding the to controllers right method but not the parameter's value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, http-get, html.actionlink

In my view I have

```
<dt>User Name</dt>
<dd>@Model.UserName</dd>
```

This shows proper user name, also I have an `Html.ActionLink` in the same view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangeNonAdminPassword", "Account", new { area = ""},new{userName=Model.UserName})
```

Though this actionlink sends me to right controller method but the userName value i'm getting is always `null`.

Here is the get method in controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeNonAdminPassword(string userName)
{
    var changePassword = new ChangePassword {UserName = userName};
    return View(changePassword);
}
```

The question is why is the **userName** always null in get method, and what should I do to send the proper value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `userName` into the HTML Attributes overload. You need to add it to the route values overload, the same as `area`. Use this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangeNonAdminPassword", "Account", new { area = "", userName = Model.UserName}, new {})
```

Comment: when I do that, it says `cannot resolve action 'ChangeNonAdminPassword'`

Comment: Sorry, left out the required overload for HTML attributes! These need to be empty to let MVC pick the correct method - answer updated